# Remove a file from folder using changeable path folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I want to remove folder that existe in many project in the same workspace folder  like below :

Workspace : 
                  /project1/generated 
                 /project2/generated

I tried the code below,but deosn't work :

```
del /q "workspace\(*)\generated\*"
FOR /D %%p IN ("workspace\(*)\generated\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
```

Please can someone help ?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: You need to clarify whether you're trying to **_remove_** the `generated` directories, or **_empty_** them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deleting the directory (and all files it contains), then the following will work. When you are confident that the correct directories will be deleted, delete the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` command.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\workspace\project*\generated' | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

If you must do it from a cmd.exe shell or .bat script, you could:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\workspace\project*\generated' | " ^
        "Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf"
```